Image is rendered in white rather than the actual image using react-pdf in node.js
I am having a problem with showing images in my pdf generator that I am using @react-pdf/renderer, I switching the process of creating the PDF from client-side to server-side to reduce the load on the browser when creating the pdf. The API itself is working, I made a Post method to handle the request and it's working very fine except when rendering the image, the image itself doesn't show in the pdf.
This is the main script index.js
require("../babel-register");

const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const React = require("react");
const ReactDOMServer = require("react-dom/server");
const { pdf } = require("@react-pdf/renderer");
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const WorksheetDocument = require("./components/pdf/WorksheetDocument");

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// Middleware to parse JSON bodies
app.use(express.json({ limit: "100mb" }));

// Enable CORS for all routes
app.use(cors());

app.use("/static", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../public/assets")));

app.post("/generate-worksheet", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const input = req.body;

    if (!input || !input.worksheet) {
      return res.status(400).send("Invalid input");
    }

    const document = React.createElement(WorksheetDocument, {
      worksheet: input.worksheet,
    });

    // Generate PDF buffer
    const pdfInstance = pdf(document);
    const pdfBuffer = await pdfInstance.toString();

    const filePath = path.join(__dirname, "output.pdf");

    // Write buffer to file
    fs.writeFile(filePath, pdfBuffer, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error("Error writing PDF file:", err);
        return res.status(500).send("Error generating PDF");
      }
      res.sendFile(filePath);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error generating PDF:", error);
    res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
  }
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});

This is the react component that I am using to build the pdf which is called WorksheetDocument
const React = require("react");
const path = require("path");
const {
  Font,
  Page,
  Text,
  View,
  Document,
  StyleSheet,
  Image,
} = require("@react-pdf/renderer");

const arabicFont =
  "http://localhost:3000/static/fonts/Rubic/static/Rubik-Bold.ttf";
const worksheetBackground =
  "http://localhost:3000/static/img/MathMania/WorksheetBackground.png";

const WorksheetDocument = ({ worksheet }) => {
  const currentLanguage = worksheet?.settings?.lang?.value;
  let numbersNotaion = "ar-EG";

  if (currentLanguage != "ar") {
    numbersNotaion = "en";
  }

  const abjadValues = ["أ", "ب", "ج", "د", "ه"];

  if (
    !worksheet?.selections?.learningObjectives ||
    !worksheet?.selections?.questions
  ) {
    return null;
  }

  const { selections } = worksheet;
  const { learningObjectives, questions } = selections;

  let pages = [1];
  Object.keys(learningObjectives || {})?.map((lo) => {
    const LO = learningObjectives?.[lo];
    const questions = worksheet?.selections?.questions?.[LO?.id];
    let questionPerPage = 0;

    if (questions?.length > 0) {
      if (!!questions[0]?.question?.image_path_Dashboard) {
        questionPerPage = 2;
      } else {
        questionPerPage = 4;
      }
      pages.push(
        pages[pages?.length - 1] +
          Math.ceil(questions?.length / questionPerPage)
      );
    }
  });

  Font.register({
    family: "Rubik",
    src: arabicFont,
  });

  Font.registerEmojiSource({
    format: "png",
    url: "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twemoji/14.0.2/72x72/",
  });

  Font.registerHyphenationCallback((word) => {
    return [word];
  });

  const imageStyle = StyleSheet.create({
    imageContainer: {
      flexDirection: "row",
      justifyContent: "center",
      width: "100%",
      alignItems: "center",
      marginTop: 0,
    },
    image: {
      width: 200,
      height: 200,
    },
    worksheetBackgroundContainer: {
      width: "100%",
      height: "100%",
      padding: 0,
      margin: 0,
      position: "absolute",
    },
    worksheetBackground: {
      width: "100%",
      height: "100%",
      position: "absolute",
      top: "-5%",
    },
  });

  const coverPage = StyleSheet.create({
    schoolName: {
      flexDirection: "row",
      justifyContent: "center",
      width: "100%",
      alignItems: "center",
      marginTop: 5,
      fontSize: 20,
      fontFamily: "Rubik",
      fontWeight: "bold",
    },
    worksheetName: {
      flexDirection: "row",
      justifyContent: "center",
      width: "100%",
      alignItems: "center",
      marginTop: 5,
      fontSize: 21,
      fontFamily: "Rubik",
      fontWeight: "bold",
      letterSpacing: currentLanguage == "ar" ? 0 : 15,
    },
    worksheetNumber: {
      flexDirection: "row",
      justifyContent: "center",
      width: "100%",
      alignItems: "center",
      marginTop: 380,
      fontSize: 20,
      fontFamily: "Rubik",
      fontWeight: "bold",
    },
    teacherName: {
      flexDirection: "row",
      justifyContent: "center",
      width: "100%",
      alignItems: "center",
      marginTop: 10,
      fontSize: 25,
      fontFamily: "Rubik",
      fontWeight: "bold",
    },
    className: {
      flexDirection: "row",
      justifyContent: "center",
      width: "100%",
      alignItems: "center",
      marginTop: 5,
      fontSize: 15,
      fontFamily: "Rubik",
      fontWeight: "bold",
    },
    date: {
      flexDirection: "row",
      justifyContent: "center",
      width: "100%",
      alignItems: "center",
      marginTop: 10,
      fontSize: 25,
      fontFamily: "Rubik",
      fontWeight: "bold",
    },
  });

  const pageLayout = StyleSheet.create({
    header: {
      borderBottom: "4px solid black",
      width: "90%",
      height: "auto",
      marginTop: "2%",
      marginHorizontal: "5%",
      marginBottom: "10",
      fontFamily: "Rubik",
      fontWeight: "bold",
      fontSize: 15,
      textAlign: currentLanguage == "ar" ? "right" : "left",
    },
    headerText: {
      paddingBottom: "1%",
    },
    footer: {
      borderTop: "1px dashed black",
      width: "90%",
      marginHorizontal: "5%",
      position: "absolute",
      bottom: 0,
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      fontFamily: "Rubik",
    },
    footerContainer: {
      flexDirection: "row",
      justifyContent: "space-around",
      width: "100%",
      alignItems: "center",
      paddingTop: "2%",
      fontFamily: "Rubik",
    },
    footerSchool: {
      fontWeight: "bold",
      fontSize: 15,
      textAlign: "left",
      paddingBottom: "3%",
      fontFamily: "Rubik",
    },
    footerName: {
      fontWeight: "bold",
      fontSize: 15,
      textAlign: "center",
      paddingBottom: "3%",
      fontFamily: "Rubik",
    },
    footerNumber: {
      fontWeight: "bold",
      fontSize: 15,
      textAlign: "right",
      paddingBottom: "3%",
      fontFamily: "Rubik",
    },
    fakeFooter: {
      width: "90%",
      height: "10%",
      marginTop: "2%",
      marginHorizontal: "5%",
    },
  });

  const questionsLayout = StyleSheet.create({
    page: {
      flexDirection: "column",
      width: "100%",
    },
    MQCsection: {
      alignItems: currentLanguage == "ar" ? "flex-end" : "flex-start",
      width: "100%",
      marginBottom: 10,
      padding: 10,
    },
    fillInBlankSection: {
      width: "100%",
      marginBottom: 10,
      padding: 10,
    },
    question: {
      fontSize: 12,
      padding: 5,
      marginBottom: 5,
      fontFamily: "Rubik",
      fontWeight: "bold",
    },
    questionContainer: {
      width: "100%",
      flexDirection: "row",
      marginBottom: 5,
      fontFamily: "Rubik",
      justifyContent: currentLanguage == "ar" ? "flex-end" : "flex-start",
      paddingTop: 10,
      alignItems: "center",
    },
    questionIndex: {
      borderRadius: "50%",
      padding: 5,
      backgroundColor: "#3C3D8E",
      color: "white",
      textAlign: "center",
      marginRight: currentLanguage == "ar" ? 0 : 10,
      marginLeft: currentLanguage == "ar" ? 10 : 0,
      fontFamily: "Rubik",
      display: "flex",
      fontWeight: "bold",
      fontSize: 13,
    },
    answer: {
      fontSize: 20,
      marginBottom: 2,
      paddingLeft: 10,
      fontFamily: "Rubik",
    },
    blank: {
      borderBottom: "1px dashed black",
      marginTop: 35,
      width: "100%",
    },
    questionImage: {
      width: 200,
      height: 200,
      marginLeft: currentLanguage == "ar" ? "0%" : "6%",
      marginRight: currentLanguage == "ar" ? "6%" : "0%",
      alignSelf: currentLanguage == "ar" ? "flex-end" : "flex-start",
    },
    questionText: {
      width: "100%",
      flexDirection: "row",
      fontFamily: "Rubik",
      justifyContent: currentLanguage == "ar" ? "flex-end" : "flex-start",
      alignContent: currentLanguage == "ar" ? "flex-end" : "flex-start",
      alignItems: "center",
    },
    questionBox: {
      width: "100%",
      flexDirection: "column",
      fontFamily: "Rubik",
      paddingTop: 5,
    },
  });

  const tableOfContentLayout = StyleSheet.create({
    body: {
      width: "100%",
      height: "100%",
      padding: 20,
      fontFamily: "Rubik",
      backgroundColor: "#f2f2f2",
      flexDirection: "column",
      alignItems: "center",
      alignContent: "flex-start",
      justifyContent: "flex-start",
    },
    table: {
      display: "table",
      width: "auto",
      margin: 20,
      borderStyle: "solid",
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: "#bfbfbf",
    },
    tableRow: {
      flexDirection: "row",
    },
    tableColHeader: {
      width: "50%",
      borderStyle: "solid",
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: "#bfbfbf",
      backgroundColor: "#f2f2f2",
    },
    tableCol: {
      width: "50%",
      borderStyle: "solid",
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: "#bfbfbf",
    },
    tableCellHeader: {
      margin: 5,
      fontSize: 15,
      fontWeight: "bold",
      textAlign: "center",
    },
    tableCell: {
      margin: 5,
      fontSize: 15,
      textAlign: "center",
    },
    title: {
      fontSize: 30,
      textAlign: "center",
      margin: 10,
      marginTop: "10%",
      fontWeight: "bold",
    },
  });

  return (
    <Document>
      <Page>
        <View style={imageStyle.worksheetBackgroundContainer}>
          <Image
            style={imageStyle.worksheetBackground}
            src={worksheetBackground}
          />
        </View>

        <View style={coverPage.schoolName}>
          <Text>{worksheet?.settings?.school?.name}</Text>
        </View>

        <View style={coverPage.worksheetName}>
          <Text>{worksheet?.settings?.worksheetName}</Text>
        </View>

        <View style={coverPage.className}>
          <Text>{worksheet?.settings?.className}</Text>
        </View>

        <View style={coverPage.worksheetNumber}>
          <Text>
            {currentLanguage == "ar" ? "ورقة العمل" : "Worksheet"}{" "}
            {worksheet?.settings?.worksheetNumber}
          </Text>
        </View>

        <View style={coverPage.teacherName}>
          <Text>{worksheet?.settings?.teacherName}</Text>
        </View>

        <View style={coverPage.date}>
          <Text>{worksheet?.settings?.date}</Text>
        </View>
      </Page>

      <Page size="A4" style={tableOfContentLayout.body}>
        <Text style={tableOfContentLayout.title}>
          {currentLanguage == "ar" ? "قائمة المحتويات" : "Table Of Contents"}
        </Text>
        <View style={tableOfContentLayout.table}>
          <View style={tableOfContentLayout.tableRow}>
            <View style={tableOfContentLayout.tableColHeader}>
              <Text style={tableOfContentLayout.tableCellHeader}>
                {currentLanguage == "ar" ? "الصفحات" : "Learning Objectives"}
              </Text>
            </View>
            <View style={tableOfContentLayout.tableColHeader}>
              <Text style={tableOfContentLayout.tableCellHeader}>
                {currentLanguage == "ar" ? "الأهداف التعليمية" : "Pages"}
              </Text>
            </View>
          </View>
          {Object.keys(learningObjectives || {})?.map((lo, index) => (
            <View style={tableOfContentLayout.tableRow} key={index}>
              <View style={tableOfContentLayout.tableCol}>
                <Text style={tableOfContentLayout.tableCell}>
                  {currentLanguage == "ar"
                    ? `${(pages[index] + 2).toLocaleString(
                        numbersNotaion
                      )} - ${(pages[index + 1] + 1).toLocaleString(
                        numbersNotaion
                      )}`
                    : learningObjectives?.[lo]?.name?.[currentLanguage]}
                </Text>
              </View>
              <View style={tableOfContentLayout.tableCol}>
                <Text style={tableOfContentLayout.tableCell}>
                  {currentLanguage != "ar"
                    ? `${pages[index] + 2} - ${pages[index + 1] + 1}`
                    : learningObjectives?.[lo]?.name?.[currentLanguage]}
                </Text>
              </View>
            </View>
          ))}
        </View>
      </Page>

      {Object.keys(learningObjectives || {})?.map((lo, loIndex) => (
        <Page size="A4" key={loIndex} wrap>
          <View style={pageLayout.header} fixed>
            <Text style={pageLayout.headerText}>{`${
              currentLanguage == "ar" ? "الهدف التعليمي" : "Learning Objectives"
            }: ${learningObjectives?.[lo]?.name?.[currentLanguage]}`}</Text>
          </View>

          <View style={questionsLayout.page} wrap={true}>
            <View>
              {(questions?.[lo] || [])?.map((question, index) => (
                <View
                  key={index}
                  style={
                    question?.type == 1
                      ? questionsLayout.fillInBlankSection
                      : questionsLayout.MQCsection
                  }
                  wrap={false}
                >
                  <View style={questionsLayout.questionContainer}>
                    {currentLanguage === "ar" ? (
                      <View style={questionsLayout.questionBox}>
                        <View style={questionsLayout.questionText}>
                          <Text style={questionsLayout.question}>
                            {`${question?.question?.[currentLanguage]}`}
                          </Text>
                          <Text style={questionsLayout.questionIndex}>
                            {(index + 1).toLocaleString(numbersNotaion)}
                          </Text>
                        </View>
                        {!!question?.question?.image_path_Dashboard && (
                          <Image
                            style={questionsLayout.questionImage}
                            src={question?.question?.image_path_Dashboard}
                          />
                        )}
                      </View>
                    ) : (
                      <View style={questionsLayout.questionBox}>
                        <View style={questionsLayout.questionText}>
                          <Text style={questionsLayout.questionIndex}>
                            {(index + 1).toLocaleString(numbersNotaion)}
                          </Text>
                          <Text style={questionsLayout.question}>
                            {`${question?.question?.[currentLanguage]}`}
                          </Text>
                        </View>
                        {!!question?.question?.image_path_Dashboard && (
                          <Image
                            style={questionsLayout.questionImage}
                            src={question?.question?.image_path_Dashboard}
                          />
                        )}
                      </View>
                    )}
                  </View>

                  {question?.type == 1
                    ? Array.from({ length: 3 }, (_, i) => (
                        <View key={i} style={questionsLayout.blank}></View>
                      ))
                    : question?.answers?.map((answer, index) => (
                        <Text key={index} style={questionsLayout.answer}>
                          {currentLanguage == "ar"
                            ? `${abjadValues[index]}- ${answer?.[currentLanguage]}`
                            : `${String.fromCharCode(
                                "A".charCodeAt(0) + index
                              )}- ${answer?.[currentLanguage]}`}
                        </Text>
                      ))}
                </View>
              ))}
            </View>
          </View>
          <View style={pageLayout.fakeFooter} fixed></View>

          <View style={pageLayout.footer} fixed>
            <View style={pageLayout.footerContainer}>
              <Text style={pageLayout.footerSchool}>
                {worksheet?.settings?.school?.name}
              </Text>
              <Text style={pageLayout.footerName}>
                {worksheet?.settings?.worksheetName}
              </Text>
              <Text
                style={pageLayout.footerNumber}
                render={({ pageNumber }) =>
                  `©️ mathmania | ${pageNumber?.toLocaleString(numbersNotaion)}`
                }
              />
            </View>
          </View>
        </Page>
      ))}
    </Document>
  );
};

module.exports = WorksheetDocument;

The path of the image that I want to render is stored in const worksheetBackground, I am using the image in a static folder using express.static , as using the image in a relative paths didn't work, when I using them in a static folder they increased the pdf file size but they are not shown in the pdf.

Thank you for your feedback @KJ, I swithced to another library which is PDFKit, and the images are rendered successfully, probably it has to be something with the library itself
